# Problems SSH authentication in AWS

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, cisco, authentication

I'm running docker Yang Development Kit for python ydk-py in my remote  Ubuntu server. I would like to establish a connection using with the remote server and my AWS EC2 instance that runs CSR 1000v (SSH authentication)

Before hand, I used to access my router using the following ssh command:

`ssh -i "ssh-key.pem" ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`
Where e`c2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` is the hostname, `ec2-user` is the username and the ssh key `ssh-key.pem` is for authentification.

As the first step, I want to run the given example in here [ydk-py samples](https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/ydk-py-samples.)

This is the python code for creation of NETCONF session in the given example:

```
    provider = NetconfServiceProvider(address="10.0.0.1",
                                      port=830,
                                      username="admin",
                                      password="admin",
                                      protocol="ssh")
```

I have tried this

```
provider = NetconfServiceProvider(address="ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", 
username= "ec2-user", 
 public_key_path="mykey.pem")
```

I have got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello-ydk.py", line 18, in <module>
    private_key_path="mykey.pem")
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. ydk_.providers.NetconfServiceProvider(repo: ydk_.path.Repository, address: unicode, username: unicode, password: unicode, port: int=830L, protocol: unicode=u'ssh', on_demand: bool=True, timeout: int=-1L)
    2. ydk_.providers.NetconfServiceProvider(address: unicode, username: unicode, password: unicode, port: int=830L, protocol: unicode=u'ssh', on_demand: bool=True, common_cache: bool=False, timeout: int=-1L)
    3. ydk_.providers.NetconfServiceProvider(repo: ydk_.path.Repository, address: unicode, username: unicode, private_key_path: unicode, public_key_path: unicode, port: int=830L, on_demand: bool=True, timeout: int=-1L)
    4. ydk_.providers.NetconfServiceProvider(address: unicode, username: unicode, private_key_path: unicode, public_key_path: unicode, port: int=830L, on_demand: bool=True, common_cache: bool=False, timeout: int=-1L)

Invoked with: 'ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 'ec2-user'; kwargs: repo=None, public_key_path='mykey.pem'
```

I tried to debug the python script and it turns out that there is problem with argument type which is private_key_path.

```
-> username="ec2-user",
(Pdb) next
> /home/server/shared_files/hello-ydk.py(15)<module>()
-> private_key_path="/home/server/shared_files/mykey.pem")
(Pdb) next
TypeError: "__init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:\n    .../home/server/shared_files/mykey.pem', address='ec2-35-166-239-202.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com'"
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `ydk` is asking you to provide both the private and public key, when defining your `NetconfServiceProvider`:

```
 4. ydk_.providers.NetconfServiceProvider(address: unicode, username: unicode, private_key_path: unicode, public_key_path: unicode, port: int=830L, on_demand: bool=True, common_cache: bool=False, timeout: int=-1L)
```

So you would need to use:

```
provider = NetconfServiceProvider(address="ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", 
  username= "ec2-user", 
  private_key_path="mykey.pem", 
  public_key_path="mykey.pub")
```

Comment: I have already tried it, and here what I got
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello-ydk.py", line 16, in <module>
    public_key_path="/home/server/shared_files/mykey.pem")
RuntimeError: YClientError: Could not connect to ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`